# Can DragonEgg run an optimization pass available in gcc and produce llvm IR?

Tags: gcc, llvm, llvm-gcc, llvm-ir

Is it possible to run a gcc optimization pass on any code and in the end obtain llvm IR? I want to use dead store elimination available in gcc. I am aware that llvm also has this pass but it is not as advanced as in gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with it and I haven't tried, but I think the following command-line should work in DragonEgg version 3.0 and above:

`-fplugin=./dragonegg.so -O0 -fdse -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-enable-gcc-optzns -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-llvm-ir-optimize=2 -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-emit-ir -S`

- `-fplugin=./dragonegg.so` enables DragonEgg
- `-O0` turns off all GCC optimization passes
- `-fdse` turns on GCC dead store elimination
- `-fplugin-arg-dragonegg-enable-gcc-optzns` enables GCC optimizations in DragonEgg
- `-fplugin-arg-dragonegg-llvm-ir-optimize=2` forces LLVM to optimize to `-O2` instead of following the GCC optimization level
- `-fplugin-arg-dragonegg-emit-ir` generates LLVM IR instead of asm, which according to the question is what you want here
- `-S` because you kinda need it when you use `-fplugin-arg-dragonegg-emit-ir`

And this should work on any [GCC tree pass](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Tree-SSA-passes.html).

If you need more fine-grained control than this, you can tweak DragonEgg: the correct place to edit is the `plugin_init` function in [Backend.cpp](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/dragonegg/trunk/src/Backend.cpp) - you can see precisely how it sets up the passes to run there.